# Difference between a DynamicMessage and a typed Message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, typing

I'm trying to understand more about protobuf `DynamicMessage`. If I have a message Animal that is coming from an input stream, code that has the Animal protoc java type (say `AnimalProto`) will use that type directly to deserialize. Whereas a code without the compile time dependency on `AnimalProto` but has access to the Type descriptor will use that Type descriptor to deserialize from the input stream into a `DynamicMessage` object.

What is the difference between the deserialized `AnimalProto` object and the `DynamcicMessage` object? As far as the jvm is concerned `.equals()` will obviously return false. Are their serialized formats the same, i.e. if I were to send them over the wire again, the format would be the same regardless of which method it was constructed using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, their serialized formats will remain the same.

The `AnimalProto` object simply has the `AnimalProto` API -- you can get its fields by name, for example.